# Working with Mongo data is not entered into database

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express

Is there any things i should add earlier for referenece.... I have tried many solutions from everywhere

```javascript
var express = require('express');
    var router = express.Router();
    var MongoClient = require('mongodb').MongoClient;


/* GET home page. */
    router.get('/', function(req, res, next) {
       res.render('index', { title: 'Express' });
    });

    router.post('/submit',(req,res)=>{
      console.log(req.body)


      MongoClient.connect("mongodb://localhost:27017", function(err, client) {
        console.log('a')
      if(err) {
        console.log(err);
      }
      else{
        console.log("connected")
      }
    });

      res.send('got it')


    });

    module.exports = router;
```

The terminal shows this

```
[nodemon] 2.0.20
    [nodemon] to restart at any time, enter `rs`
    [nodemon] watching path(s): *.*
    [nodemon] watching extensions: js,mjs,json
    [nodemon] starting `node ./bin/www`
    GET / 304 330.615 ms - -
    GET /stylesheets/style.css 304 12.886 ms - -
    POST /submit 200 120.211 ms - 6
    [nodemon] restarting due to changes...
    [nodemon] starting `node ./bin/www`
    [Object: null prototype] {
      first_name: '',
      last_name: '',
      email: '',
      pw: '',
      pw_confirm: ''
    }
    POST /submit 200 140.756 ms - 6
```

here is my html code

```html
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12 col-lg-12">
            <form action="/submit" method="post" role="form" enctype="application/x-www-form-urlencoded">
                <legend>Enter Registration Information Here</legend>

                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="first_name">First Name</label>
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" name="first_name" id="first_name" placeholder="First Name">
                </div>

                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="last_name">Last Name</label>
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" name="last_name" id="first_name" placeholder="Last Name">
                </div>

                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="email">Email Address</label>
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" name="email" id="email" placeholder="Email Address">
                </div>

                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="pw">Password</label>
                    <input type="password" class="form-control" name="pw" id="pw">
                </div>

                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="pw_confirm">Confirm Password</label>
                    <input type="password" class="form-control" name="pw_confirm" id="pw_confirm">
                </div>

                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

after this console message nothing is being printed... I tried many things but couldn't find answer.... even there is no error message... please help me to find answer... I would like to get the output in terminal as 'err message or connected message"... the values are getting entered but the only problem is the values in `MongoClient.connect` to `console.log('connected')` is not getting printed in terminal

Comment: Do you have a name attribute in html form ?

Comment: @NaveenRavi Now i have added my Html code too... Thanks

Comment: @NaveenRavi i have left the columns blank... i haven't entered any data.. the expected output is   "connected or err or a"

Comment: well that depends on your mongoconnection .  you can refer mongo docs in its website